# When creating react app this error appears: Cannot find module './lib/pack.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I execute the command:

> npx create-react-app opencord

After doing so this error shows up:

[image: Error message in console]

What can I do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/984422) when asking a question.

Comment: Looks like the error comes from the `tar` module at [this line](https://github.com/npm/node-tar/blob/main/index.js#L11). Can you check if the module is installed properly and that the `lib/pack.js` file exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem o Linux by deleting the npm cache folder `/home/<user>/.npm/`.

You might be able to resolve this on Windows by deleting the folder `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\npm-cache\`.

Apparently you can reach the same result by running the command `npm cache clean` as well. (You might need to use `--force` flag)